# Java - switch: case 2 and 3 do not function

Tags: java, arraylist, switch-statement, tostring

I was wondering if someone could shed some light as to why case 2 and 3 in my code seem to not do anything, and perhaps offer some advice. I will offer whatever information I think is relevant, and will add more if you request more details.

Let me offer some details before posting my code: My program is designed to be a very simple employee database. It offers the user options on the command line using a switch statement. The options from the switch are:

1. Add an employee to the database
2. List all employees in the database, and view wages and hours worked
3. List all employees and display corporate benefits, if any
4. Terminate the program

Case 1 adds an Employee object to an ArrayList of type Employee. The Employee class is responsible for keeping track of the employee names, wages, hours, and companies that they work for.

Case 1 and 4 seem to function properly.

However, case 2 and 3 do not seem to do anything. Here is the entirety of the switch, which is located in the driver class that contains the main method:

```
        ArrayList<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();

    int number = 0;

    while(number != 4)
    {

        System.out.print("Please select an option: " +
                "\n1) Add an Employee" +
                "\n2) List Employees" +
                "\n3) List Benefit Status" +
                "\n4) Quit"+ "\n");
        number = keyboard.nextInt();
        keyboard.nextLine();

        switch (number)
        {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Hourly, contract, or salary employee? ");
                type = keyboard.nextLine();

                if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("hourly"))
                {
                    System.out.print("\nEnter the company: ");
                    comp = keyboard.nextLine();
                    System.out.print("\nEnter the first name: ");
                    fn = keyboard.nextLine();
                    System.out.print("\nEnter the last name: ");
                    ln = keyboard.nextLine();
                    System.out.print("\nEnter the hourly wage: ");
                    wage = keyboard.nextDouble();
                    System.out.print("\nEnter the hours worked: ");
                    hours = keyboard.nextInt();

                    Employee employee2 = new Employee(comp, fn, ln);
                    HourlyEmployee he = new HourlyEmployee(wage, hours);
                }

                else if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("contract"))
                {
                    System.out.print("\nEnter the company: ");
                                        comp = keyboard.nextLine();
                                        System.out.print("\nEnter the first name: ");
                                        fn = keyboard.nextLine();
                                        System.out.print("\nEnter the last name: ");
                                        ln = keyboard.nextLine();
                                        System.out.print("\nEnter the hourly wage: ");
                                        wage = keyboard.nextDouble();
                                        System.out.print("\nEnter the hours worked: ");
                                        hours = keyboard.nextInt();

                                        Employee employee2 = new Employee(comp, fn, ln);
                    ContractEmployee ce = new ContractEmployee(wage, hours);
                }

                else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("salary"))
                {
                                        System.out.print("\nEnter the company: ");
                                        comp = keyboard.nextLine();
                                        System.out.print("\nEnter the first name: ");
                                        fn = keyboard.nextLine();
                                        System.out.print("\nEnter the last name: ");
                                        ln = keyboard.nextLine();
                                        System.out.print("\nEnter the salary: ");
                    salary = keyboard.nextDouble();

                    Employee employee2 = new Employee(comp, fn, ln);
                    SalaryEmployee se = new SalaryEmployee(salary);
                }

                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Invalid input.");
                    System.exit(0);
                }

                break;
            case 2:
                for(int i = 0; i < employees.size(); i++)
                {
                    System.out.println(employees.get(i).toString());
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                for(int i = 0; i < employees.size(); i++)
                {
                    System.out.println(employees.get(i).determineBenefits());
                }
                break;
            case 4:
                System.exit(0);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid input.");
                System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

}

In case 2 and 3, I am attempting to pass indexes of the ArrayList as arguments to the toString() method and to the determineBenefits() methods, respectively. When those methods are tested separately from the switch, they same to function properly. Here is the toString() method:

```
    public String toString()
{
    return firstName + " " + lastName + " from " + company +
            ". The worker's pay this week was $" + pay + ".";
}
```

And the determineBenefits() method:

```
    public String determineBenefits()
{
    String benefits;

    if(isSalaryEmployee == true)
    {
        benefits = "This employee has a standard company health " +
            "insurance policy.";
    }

    else if(hhh  >= 40)
    {
        benefits = "This worker gets benefits.";
    }

    else
    {
        benefits = "No benefits.";
    }

    return benefits;
}
```

And the Employee constructors, in case that is relevant:

```
public Employee()
{

}

public Employee(String com, String first, String last)
{
    setCompany(com);
    setFirstName(first);
    setLastName(last);
}
```

So, how should I go about passing the Employee objects located in the ArrayList?

Comment: You are not adding `Employee` objects to the `employees` list anywhere, so when you print the content of the list (cases 2 and 3) nothing is printed because the list is empty.

Comment: Side note: your code is overly complex. Don't just push line after line after line. Consider to break things into small methods instead. You should not do cascaded if/else within a switch within a loop. Such code becomes unmaintainable ... maybe 5 minutes after you wrote it

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, Jesper. That was the problem, and a very simple error of omission that was easy to solve. Marking as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, my problem was that I forgot to actually add the Employee objects to the ArrayList, which was a very simple error to fix. Thank you to all who answered.